# angular-gridster2.mjs , Error: export 'debounceTime' (imported as 'debounceTime') was not found in 'rxjs'

Tags: npm, rxjs, node-modules, angular-gridster2, angular14upgrade

I have upgraded my angular version from 12 to 14.

After that I have received many error which I resolved but in the end I for the following error I'm not sure what I should do. The angular-gridster2.mjs is one of the packages that has installed and is in the nodemodules.

[image]

I also have updated the rxjs and rxjs-compat as follow:

```
 "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
 "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
```

does any one has any idea what could be the problem?

I have tried to downgrade the gridster2 and also rxjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator functions are not exported under `rxjs` in this RxJS version. They are located under `rxjs/operators`.

```js
// "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators"
```

If you can't change the imports, you may upgrade RxJS to the latest version.

```js
// "rxjs": "^7.5.7",
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs"
```

Comment: angular-gridster2.mjs file is in nodemodules and Im not be able to modify the import inside this file. is this what you mean?  I guess this is s.th that should be fixed inside the package (angular-gridster2) itself

Comment: @Shide - Ah I see now. Those errors originate in files you did not write. In this case you cant change the import here. Another option would be to upgrade rxjs to a version larger than `7.5`. There, the import via `rxjs` is possible again.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by upgrading the RxJS library to v7.5.5.

[Solution reference link](https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2/issues/820)